# Нужно отправить картинку multipart или base64 формой (rucaptcha) через python

Tags: python, post, base64, multipart

Нужно отправить картинку вот такой формой на сервер POST запросом

```
<form method="post" action="http://rucaptcha.com/in.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="post">
Ваш ключ:
<input type="text" name="key" value="YOUR_APIKEY">
Файл капчи:
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить и получить ID">
</form>
```

Либо такой формой:

```
<form method="post" action="http://rucaptcha.com/in.php">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="base64">
Ваш ключ:
<input type="text" name="key" value="YOUR_APIKEY">
Тело файла капчи в формате base64:
<textarea name="body">BASE64_FILE</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить и получить ID">
</form>
```

Как мне на пайтоне это сделать? У меня есть сохраненная картинка(jpeg) и API key

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используйте модуль `requests`: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: Ну или вот на русском https://docs-python.ru/packages/modul-requests-python/get-post-zaprosy-modulem-requests/

Comment: библиотеку requests для пайтона я уже установил, не понимаю как мне в пайтон коде указать все нужные параметры, например:
import requests
response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data={'method': 'post'})
в выводе получаю:
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "method": "post" }

т.е. вроде добавился метод - пост, а как прописать, чтобы добавились остальные параметры?

Comment: как добавить блок <input> в пост запрос через пайтон?